# Java 8 post grouping by

Tags: java, grouping, java-stream

I have a list of objects of class Job, every object has a collection of tags (networks), this collection is mutable and has no impact on hashCode and objects equality.

What I need to do is to get a list of all unique Job objects and for each such object combine all tags, for example, I have a list:

`[{position: "CTO", dates: "2012-2014", city: "New York", networks: ["foo"]}, {position: "CTO", dates: "2012-2014", city: "New York", networks: ["bar"]}]`

This should be reduced to `[{position: "CTO", dates: "2012-2014", city: "New York", networks: ["foo", "bar"]}]`

```
public class Job {
    private final String position;
    private final String dates;
    private final Integer startYear;
    private final Integer endYear;
    private final String city;
    private Set<NetworkType> networks;

    public String getPosition() {
        return position;
    }

    public String getDates() {
        return dates;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public Set<NetworkType> getNetworks() {
        return networks;
    }

    public void setNetworks(Set<NetworkType> networks) {
        this.networks = networks;
    }

    public Integer getStartYear() {
        return startYear;
    }

    public Integer getEndYear() {
        return endYear;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!(o instanceof Job)) {
            return false;
        }
        Job job = (Job) o;
        return Objects.equals(position, job.position) &&
                Objects.equals(dates, job.dates) &&
                Objects.equals(city, job.city);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(position, dates, city);
    }
}
```

This is the actual Job class code, and that is how I implemented this operation:

```
    Map<Job, List<Job>> jobsMap = jobs.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(job -> job));
    jobsMap.keySet().stream()
            .peek(job -> jobsMap.get(job).stream().forEach(j -> job.getNetworks().addAll(j.getNetworks())))
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing((Job o) -> Objects.firstNonNull(o.getEndYear(), Integer.MAX_VALUE))
                    .reversed())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But I feel very bad for this code, especially since I am using external map inside the stream and I wonder is there any way to do that in one chain without intermediate transformations. 
I would appreciate any valid criticism about my implementation of this functionality.
Thank you!

Comment: You need to `groupBy` your `Job` by `position` then use a custom collector to merge your `List<Job>` in the `Map` into a single `Job`.

Comment: If the other fields like `city` are different, should the networks still be merged to the other job?

Comment: No, actually, I am grouping objects by equality groupingBy(job -> job). Networks field isn't taking part in equals.

Comment: Updated my answer so the example won't be confusing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that we will merge all the `networks` into the **first** occurrence of a particular `Job` that we find, we can do this in one (rather complex) line:

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;
import static java.util.function.Function.identity;

Map<Job, Optional<Job>> collect = jobs.stream()
    .collect(groupingBy(identity(), reducing((l, r) -> {
        l.networks().addAll(r.networks());
        return l;
    })));
```

<sub>I have used fluent accessors because I cannot be bothered to type `get`</sub>

So. How does this work?

First we `stream` the `jobs` and call `Collectors.groupingBy` on `Function.identity()`, this gives us a `Map<Job, List<Job>>`.

But we don't want a `List<Job>` - this is where `Collectors.reducing` comes in. This is passed as the downstream `Collector` of `groupingBy`.

The downstream `Collector` is responsible for creating the value part of the `Map` - in this case we **reduce** all the found jobs into one `Job`.

```
reducing((l, r) -> {
    l.networks().addAll(r.networks());
    return l;
}
```

So this takes two `Job` items, and returns one. It's a fold operation, so the `BiFunction` is with the `return` value in turn to each `Job`. All we do is add all the `networks()` from the new `Job` to the existing `Job`.

Obviously this gives you a `Map<String, Optional<Job>>`, but collapsing that is a simple job.

I cannot see a way to make it into a `List` directly...

---

In order to process the `Map<Job, Optional<Job>>` into a `List<Job>` the following can be used:

```
collect.values().stream()
    .map(Optional::get)
    .collect(toList);
```

So, you could potentially do the whole lot in one line:

```
List<Job> collect = jobs.stream()
    .collect(groupingBy(identity(), reducing((l, r) -> {
        l.networks().addAll(r.networks());
        return l;
    })))
    .values().stream()
    .map(Optional::get)
    .collect(toList);
```

Although, the readability of this is questionable.

Comment: Thank you very much! Could you please update your answer? First of all, we need to use the whole Job object for comparing, not position, and second of all, we can use collectingAndThen for collapsing Optionals and Map. So, this is can be done in one operation: `jobs.stream().collect(collectingAndThen(groupingBy(job -> job, collectingAndThen(
          reducing((l, r) -> {
           l.getNetworks().addAll(r.getNetworks());
           return l;
          }), Optional::get)), map -> new ArrayList<>(map.values())))`

Comment: @Skeeve will you every be able to work out what that single line of code does? It's already pretty much illegible, adding two `collectingAndThen` operations makes it completely illegible... I would suggest `.values().stream().map(Optional::get).collect(toList)` for example.

Comment: So, producing few streams wouldn't be a bad practice?

Comment: @Skeeve I think in this case it adds readability - and that should be paramount. It is easy, with the `Stream` API, to get a bit carried away with "single line" solutions and end up with so many brackets that when you come back to the code you have no clue what is going on. I don't think this solution will be any less performant that an approach with `collectingAndThen` as the majority of the work (creating the `Map`, the `List`) needs to be done in either case.

Comment: OK. Thank you very much for your help!